# Accessing google maps in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

Here is the link i used to display google maps :

https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/1krtvcfj/2/

While trying to access maps by trying this code, it shows the following error:

> Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: google is not defined"

As somebody suggested in another link I even initialised the 4 parameters like

```
geocoder: null,
map: null,
marker: null,
infowindow: null
```

I need to access google maps using this code. please somebody help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many things wrong here:

- Reference to variables should be maintained in the data component.
- Function callbacks need to use the fat arrow function, or `.bind(this)` (among other options) in order to maintain scope. This would change `function () {` to `() => {`. Otherwise, the scope of `this` within these anonymous callbacks would not be the Vue instance.
- The map its self needs to be part of the Vue template.
- The `address` input should use the `v-model` binding that Vue provides in order to keep it's data in sync with the component
- The `geocoder` service will not work without an API key.
- The base `div` in your component also needs a fixed height, or at least a height of `100%` for the map to appear correctly.
- While you can use `document.getElementById()`, I would suggest using a `ref` to maintain reference to the element, by adding `ref="map_canvas"` to the element and then using `this.$refs.map_canvas` instead.

It seems as if you've just copied and pasted some code into the Vue component and hoped it worked. It won't. I've cleaned this up for you, but I would recommend paying close attention to the differences so you can get an understanding as to how these integrate together.

Here's [your updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58g7tnov)